# I am using BLOC to make a simple counter app , but my counter is not updating when I am incrementing / decrementing it? I used BlocBuilder to build UI

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have wrapped MaterialApp under the BlocProvider and also I have used BlocBuilder for building the UI ( counter text )
I have two floating action buttons each of which call Incrementevent() and Decrementevent() respectively but still, the UI doesn't change.
please suggest a solution.

**My main.dart file**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => CounterBloc(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _counterBloc = CounterBloc();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: BlocBuilder<CounterBloc, CounterState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                ),
                Text(
                  '${state.counter}',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () => _counterBloc.add(Incrementevent()),
            tooltip: 'Decrement',
            child: Icon(Icons.remove),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () => _counterBloc.add(Decrementevent()),
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    _counterBloc.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

**My counter_event file**

```
part of 'counter_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class CounterEvent {}

class Incrementevent extends CounterEvent {}

class Decrementevent extends CounterEvent {}
```

**My counter_state file**

```
part of 'counter_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class CounterState {
  final int counter;
  const CounterState(this.counter);
}

class CounterInitial extends CounterState {
  CounterInitial(int counter) : super(counter);
}
```

**My counter_bloc file**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

part 'counter_event.dart';
part 'counter_state.dart';

class CounterBloc extends Bloc<CounterEvent, CounterState> {
  CounterBloc() : super(CounterInitial(0));

  @override
  Stream<CounterState> mapEventToState(
    CounterEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is Incrementevent) {
      yield CounterInitial(state.counter + 1);
    } else if (event is Decrementevent) {
      yield CounterInitial(state.counter - 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: use StreamBuilder instead of BlocBuilder.

Comment: I think you're missing `equatable` package in your state classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR You are creating two instances of the same BLoC, hence by triggering events on one BLoC, the other does not get updated.

In the `MyApp` widget, you create a BLoC instance and provide it to the widget tree using the `BlocProvider` - everything is perfect here.

However, in the `_MyHomePageState`, you are creating another instance of the same `CounterBloc` and using it to add events. It means, that you are operating on a different BLoC than you provided before.

To resolve this, you should get the injected BLoC instance and operate on it. Since the BLoC library depends on `provider`, you could resolve the injected BLoC like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final counterBloc = context.watch<CounterBloc>();
  ...
  floatingActionButton: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    children: [
      FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => counterBloc.add(Incrementevent()),
        tooltip: 'Decrement',
        child: Icon(Icons.remove),
      ),
      SizedBox(width: 10),
      FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => counterBloc.add(Decrementevent()),
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  ...
}
```

Or this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
  floatingActionButton: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    children: [
      FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => context.read<CounterBloc>().add(Incrementevent()),
        tooltip: 'Decrement',
        child: Icon(Icons.remove),
      ),
      SizedBox(width: 10),
      FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => context.read<CounterBloc>().add(Decrementevent()),
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  ...
}
```